# In cakephp, how to display the website without showing the name of the root folder? like, http://www.sample.com/name-of-the-main-controller/index

Tags: cakephp

In cakephp, how do we redirect to the main page of the website that you have been working on? Like, you extracted the cakephp files to the root folder named cakephp. You browse using this address,

> http://www.sample.com/cakephp-folder/name-of-the-controller/index

how do we do this in cakephp that when we browse through the site, the user will not have to see the name of the folder, and will automatically redirect to the name of the controller and the index file. Like,

> http://www.sample.com/name-of-the-controller/index

Thank you. If you can help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: show your existing folder structure please.

Comment: I have extracted my cakephp files inside C:/wamp/www/cakephp.

Comment: Then.. you could have simply moved the contents of `C:/wamp/www/cakephp/*` to `C:/wamp/www/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a virtual host for your webserver and point its document root to APP/webroot, not just APP/

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/
- http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample